# Handle errors from EventEmitter

Tags: node.js

In class which inherits EventEmitter, we usually have two points to handle error.

```
someClass.on('error', function eventEmitterCallback(err){/* handle error*/});
//and
someClass.someAsyncAction(function asyncActionCallback(err){/* handle error*/})
```

We don't know, where error can appear, and what callback will execute.
For example, [tedious](http://pekim.github.com/tedious/api-connection.html) (module for MS SQL Server):

- Incorrect password: both callbacks
- Incorrect database name: only `eventEmitterCallback`; `someAsyncAction` execute without error
- Incorrect host: only `someAsyncAction`
- Icorrect format of host IP(for example `1234.10.0.1`): node.js just down without any error :)

I want to create a simple function that will deligate all errors from module to first argument of callback.

```
function getSomeStuffFromDb(callback) { 
    var connection = new dbConnection(options);
    connection.on('error', callback);
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        /*exec SQL query*/
    }
}
```

Of course, if any error cause, I want to execute callback only once.How can I make this? How correctly union two points of error handling  in one? Maybe if in my class I use class that inherits EventEmmiter, I need enherits my class from EventEmitter too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `once` event binding if you want to avoid running the same event handler over and over. Given your code sample, I don't believe `once` and `on` will behave any differently because the `connection` object is not long-lived, but it communicates the intention a touch more clearly. Then use a closure-scope flag to avoid both the event handler and callback responding to the same underlying error.

```
function getSomeStuffFromDb(callback) { 
    var handled = false;
    var connection = new dbConnection(options);
    connection.once('error', function (err) {
        if (err && !handled) {
            handled = true;
            return callback(err);
        }
    });
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          if (handled) {
            return;
          } else {
            handled = true;
            return callback(err);
          }
        }
        /*exec SQL query*/
        callback();
    }
}
```